# How can I perform calculations with numbers millions of digits long?

Tags: c#, numbers, .net-4.5, largenumber

I've had a look around and couldn't find any useful solutions for performing calculations with numbers that are millions of digits long. There's one that links to Stack Overflow but it had been deleted.

I've come up with strategies of handling numbers 522 digits long but it is fiddly and I **have** to find a better way to do calculations when I start handling numbers which are 8 million digits long.

I'm just looking for a way to handle these numbers in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Integers or non-integers? Note that there's no such thing as "C# 4.5" - I suspect you mean .NET 4.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, sorry .NET 4.5 and integers

Comment: just don't do it :) do something else

Comment: @Andrew but I kinda need to.. :c

Comment: Have you tried BigInteger? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you need that level of precision for?

Comment: Try not to let your pc solve it - yet. There are some mathematical methods which could help you with handling such big numbers. If you could implement those in your program, you should be helped alot already.

Comment: Is this for a bioinformatics problem? I ask because I am not familiar with another field where 8 million digit fixed-precision numbers are useful, and there are specialized bioinformatics libraries which might help, like .Net Bio. (And also a bunch of more widely used non-C# tools)

Comment: @M_M I'll definitely look into .NET Bio

Comment: Python has unbounded exact integers by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) class supports arbitrarily large numbers and basic math operations.

Your best bet would probably be to implement your own number class by extending BigInteger, because existing solutions won't be optimized for your particular needs. BigInteger might do everything you need, and if you want a floating point equivalent then BigInteger isn't a bad class to model yours on.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably end up editing it - luckily I don't need to be messing around with floating points.